# Apache Camel - Call Rest-Service in Processor: Good or bad practice?

Tags: java, apache-camel

We are currently building some integration logic with Camel and have a question regarding REST-Requests.

For simple scenarios/patterns we are happy with the Camel http component. For more complex scenarios like for example **Split --> Call REST-Service n times --> aggregate** we are thinking about implementing them in a single Camel Processor instead of using the split/aggregate-functionality.

Are there any drawbacks in calling a REST Service directly from a Processor?

Comment: What was it that made you decide to implement the above in a processor instead?

Comment: I guess it is not a good idea (of course possible), but... You may loose ability of parallel execution/aggregation easily provided by Camel. Sure you can do it in your own code, but does it worth to go complex hand-written code while solution is already there?